How can I send userDefaults data to Watch?
I'm doing an basic App for create notes and subnotes in iPhone and show them in Watch. I did the both CRUD but I can't view the data in Watch. I'm using userDefaults because It's so simple app.
I tried add NSObject and WCSessionDelegate to my NoteViewModel but doesn't work. When I start the app, I get 'WCSessionActivationState(rawValue: 2)'.
Here is my NoteViewModel.swift:
import Combine
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class NoteViewModel: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var notes: [Note] = []
    
    func addNote(title: String) {
        let newNote = Note(title: title, subNotes: [])
        notes.append(newNote)
        saveNotes()
    }

    func addSubNote(to note: Note, title: String, content: String) {
        if let index = notes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == note.id }) {
            let newSubNote = SubNote(title: title, content: content)
            notes[index].subNotes.append(newSubNote)
            saveNotes()
        }
    }

    func removeNote(note: Note) {
        notes.removeAll { $0.id == note.id }
        saveNotes()
    }

    func removeSubNote(from note: Note, subNote: SubNote) {
        if let index = notes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == note.id }) {
            notes[index].subNotes.removeAll { $0.id == subNote.id }
            saveNotes()
        }
    }

    func updateNote(note: Note, newTitle: String) {
        if let index = notes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == note.id }) {
            notes[index].title = newTitle
            saveNotes()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            WCSession.default.delegate = self
            WCSession.default.activate()
            self.notes = loadNotes()
        }
    }

    func session(
        _ session: WCSession,
        activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
        error: Error?
    ) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error al activar la sesión: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Sesión activada con estado: \(activationState)")
        }
    }

    #if os(iOS)
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) { }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        session.activate()
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        if let notesArray = message["notes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: notesArray, options: []),
               let notes = try? decoder.decode([Note].self, from: data) {
                self.notes = notes
                saveNotes()
            }
        }
    }
    #endif

    private func saveNotes() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(notes) {
            if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.lucasleone.WatchNotesApp") {
                defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "notes")
            }
            sendNotesToWatch(notes: notes)
        }
    }

    private func loadNotes() -> [Note] {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.lucasleone.WatchNotesApp"),
           let savedNotes = defaults.data(forKey: "notes") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let loadedNotes = try? decoder.decode([Note].self, from: savedNotes) {
                return loadedNotes
            }
        }
        return []
    }

    private func sendNotesToWatch(notes: [Note]) {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(notes) {
            let notesDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoded, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
            if WCSession.default.isReachable {
                WCSession.default.sendMessage(["notes": notesDict ?? []], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: { error in
                    print("Error enviando mensaje: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

And in the watch, I tried this:
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = NoteViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.notes) { note in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NoteDetailView(
                            note: note, viewModel: viewModel)
                    ) {
                        Text(note.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Notas")
        }
    }
}

I'm using Xcode 16 beta, iOS 18 beta and WatchOS 11 beta.

Does your app utilize App Groups functionality?

Yes, I have 2 targets. I added 'group.lucasleone.WatchNotesApp' in both target.

Ubiquity Store is what you need UserDefaults is a local thing, you can create a property wrapper easily and use it like AppStorage

@loremipsum so I have to change userDefaults to AppStorage?

No UserDefaults and app storage are the same thing, you need the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore which can sync between devices.  You can make your own property wrapper similar to AppStorage for easy access/observing.

I tried but I coudn't , here's the repo https://github.com/LucasLeone/WatchNotesApp/tree/test

NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore uses iCloud and probably isn't the fastest way to synchronise data between an app and its companion on the watch. The advantage is that it will actually synchronise the data between all of the user's devices (say an iPad and even their Mac).  Your WCSession is connecting (state 2).  Get rid of the try ? statements and use do/try/catch in case you are getting errors in your encoding/decoding

@Paulw11 what do you recommend for synchronise data between iPhone and Watch?

The approach you are using is correct. You just need to not throw away errors and you will probably find what is going wrong
